# Resource showing red lines across the project but no errors while executing

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have `Xamarin.Android` project in Visual Studio 2017 IDE. `Resource` showing red lines everywhere by saying

> Error CS0103  The name 'Resource' does not exist in the current context

but I am able to build that project successfully. I clean & rebuild project still not getting rid of it.

How can I solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Are you able to run the project successfully? What is the use of `Resource` in your code?

Comment: In your resources folder do you have any files with names beginning with numbers? Numbers at the beginning of files is considered invalid which might be causing the errors.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya - After taking latest from TFS, those errors has gone. 
As I know `Resource` is a top level namespace in android by specifying it we can access folder, classes & controls hierarchically. Thank you.

Comment: @RichardMc - Those errors has been solved by taking latest from TFS. However there is no resource starting with digit or special character. Thank you.

Comment: @CGPA6.4 Sounds like it was a namespace error causing issues then. Glad you got through it.

Comment: @RichardMc - Yeah exactly! Even I had this thing in my mind :).

Comment: Might be worth noting that those are intellisense only errors if the project builds fine. YOu can change the "Build and Intellisense" drop down to be only "Build" and then avoid seeing those intellisense errors.

Comment: "but I am able to build that project successfully. " that is what is said in the question.

Comment: @jgoldberger-MSFT - Oh! I was out of context. Yeah I was able to build project successfully. I meant to say errors wasn't going. Than your statement seems correct. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above errors has been **solve by taking latest from TFS** & than I have Rebuild the solution. Now everything seems to be working fine.

Comment: Is your `Resource.designer.cs` being added to source control and is updated with the latest Xamarin.Android build locally? It sounds like it might be out of sync or requires a rebuild to generate a new `Resource.designer.cs`.